# Assign ToolTip style to DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

How do I assign a defined style in `Window.Resources` to the `ToolTip` style for my `DataGridTemplateColumn`?

```
<Style x:Key="StatusColumn" TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock>
                 <Run Text="Black - Inactive"/>
                 <LineBreak/>
                 <Run Text="Green - Active"/>
                  <LineBreak/>
                 <Run Text="Yellow - Update"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I am trying in this way:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50" Header="Status" IsReadOnly="True" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" >
                ?
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding Brush}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `ToolTip` as setter value and set its `Style` property using `StaticResource`.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="ToolTip">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource StatusColumn}"/>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```